# Java: Finding average and numbering lines

Tags: java, regex, loops, java.util.scanner

I've been trying to figure out how to find the average of all the ages in this set of data and also numbering each individual line. What I've done so far has only made it incomprehensible. My errors typically revolve around conversion and I am stumped on how to get by this.

I'd really appreciate the help!

Text File Contents:

```
75 Fresco, Al
67 Dwyer, Barb
55 Turner, Paige
108 Peace, Warren
46 Richman, Mary A.
37 Ware, Crystal
83 Carr, Dusty
15 Sledd, Bob
64 Sutton, Oliver
70 Mellow, Marsha
29 Case, Justin
35 Time, Justin
8 Shorts, Jim
20 Morris, Hugh
25 Vader, Ella
76 Bird, Earl E.
```

The code that I have working is:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Ex2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("people.txt"));
        while (input.hasNext()) 
        {
            String[] line = input.nextLine().replace(",", "").split("\\s+");
            String age = line[0];
            String lastName = line[1];
            String firstName = "";
            //take the rest of the input and add it to the last name
            for(int i = 2; 2 < line.length && i < line.length; i++)
                firstName += line[i] + " ";

            System.out.println(firstName + lastName + " " + age);
        }
    }
}
```

Code I have Failed Utilizing:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Ex2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("people.txt"));
        while (input.hasNext()) 
        {
            String[] line = input.nextLine().replace(",", "").split("\\s+");
            String age = line[0];
            String lastName = line[1];
            String firstName = "";
            //take the rest of the input and add it to the last name
            for(int i = 2; 2 < line.length && i < line.length; i++)
                firstName += line[i] + " ";

            for (int count = 1; line.length; count++)
                System.out.println((count+1)+ " " + line[count] + firstName + lastName + " " + age);

            int sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < line.length; j++)
                sum = sum + line[j]
                        double average = sum / line.length;
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("The average age is: " + average);
        }
    }
}
```

With an Output of:

```
Al Fresco 75
Barb Dwyer 67
Paige Turner 55
Warren Peace 108
Mary A. Richman 46
Crystal Ware 37
Dusty Carr 83
Bob Sledd 15
Oliver Sutton 64
Marsha Mellow 70
Justin Case 29
Justin Time 35
Jim Shorts 8
Hugh Morris 20
Ella Vader 25
Earl E. Bird 76
```

With a Target Output of:

```
1. Al Fresco 75
2. Barb Dwyer 67
3. Paige Turner 55
4. Warren Peace 108
5. Mary A. Richman 46
...

The average age is: NUMBER
```

Comment: Can you provide the text file content

Comment: My mistake, added it.

Comment: Go over each line of the code and describe for yourself what you think it does. Also go over de comments. See whether the code really does what you think it does. Also think whether what you think it does is even necessary. Stop programming by coincidence, start doing it with a plan.

Comment: You need to move the end printing code outside of the loop.  Also I would `sum` the age of people as I go `totAge += Integer.valueOf (line[0])`

Comment: The most [recent release](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release20#commonmath) of [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) introduced a nice new [`Stats`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/math/Stats.html) class for accumulating statistics such as the [average](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/math/Stats.html#mean--) of a data series.

Comment: Take this comment "take the rest of the input and add it to the last name". The next 2 lines are adding stuff to "first name". Not "last name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to use following code. I have done some modifications the way it can be calculate the average. It's not required to use additional for loops inside the while loop. You can calculate the average age defining two temporary variables.(`count` and `totalAge`). Then while on the loop application can increase the count to identify number of people and in the same loop you can add age in to totalAge variable. (Note that age should be cast in to Double). Then after finished the loop you can get the age by dividing totalAge by count.

I noticed that in your code average printing section added inside the while loop. It's incorrect it should be outside the while loop. Otherwise your program will print the average line after every line.

Go through following code I have added inline comments where I did the changers.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ex2 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("people.txt"));
    // to get number of people
    int count=0;
    //to get total age
    double totalAge=0;
    while (input.hasNext()) 
    {
        String[] line = input.nextLine().replace(",", "").split("\\s+");
        String age = line[0];
        String lastName = line[1];
        String firstName = "";
        //take the rest of the input and add it to the last name
        for(int i = 2; 2 < line.length && i < line.length; i++)
            firstName += line[i] + " ";

        //Convert age string into double and add it to totalAge
        totalAge=totalAge+Double.parseDouble(age);
        System.out.println(++count+" "+firstName + lastName + " " + age);
    }
    double average = totalAge / count;
    System.out.println("The average age is: " + average);
}
}
```

You can be able to get following output for your given input file.

```
1 Al Fresco 75
2 Barb Dwyer 67
3 Paige Turner 55
4 Warren Peace 108
5 Mary A. Richman 46
6 Crystal Ware 37
7 Dusty Carr 83
8 Bob Sledd 15
9 Oliver Sutton 64
10 Marsha Mellow 70
11 Justin Case 29
12 Justin Time 35
13 Jim Shorts 8
14 Hugh Morris 20
15 Ella Vader 25
16 Earl E. Bird 76
The average age is: 50.8125
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh Goodness so many ways this can be handled

Firstly in Java we try and think of things as objects in this case each line is actually an object.  To allow the code to be expanded and adjusted later start with a framework no

so we hava a new

```
Public Person(
    private int age;
    private String lastName;
    private Sring firstName;

    Public Person(int age, String lName, String fName){
       this.age = age;
       this.lastName = lname;
       this.firstName = fName;
    }
   //add getters here.
)
```

So now we have an object
 we could create a function that does

```
Array<Person> people = new ArrayList<>;
```

..for loop...

```
String[] line = input.nextLine().replace(",", "").split("\\s+");
Person p = new Person(Integer.parseint(line[0]],line[1],line[2])
people.add(p);
```

...
Alternatively you could use a  Map
...

```
Map<Integer,Person> people = new ListMap<>;
```

...
then do
people.add(p.getAge(),p)
.... 
Maps can do all sorts of sorting and filtering, depending on the type of Map you choose to use.

Finally you can then work on your object to achieve the above goal:

```
Integer total = 0
int i = 0
foreach(Person p: people){
   Integer total = total + p.getAge();
   i++
   System.out.Println(i + "." + p.getFirst() +" "+ p.getLast()+" "+ p.getAge())
}
Float average = Float.parseInt(total) / i;
System.out.Println("The average age is " + average);
```

Comment: The above code isnt tested I wouldnt use it it was designed as a example of what is achievable if you think in terms of objects rather than lines of script.